# Formatting textual "00:00 + Week Day + Date" as date-time

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a text column containing dates in the following fashion:

`01:00 Friday 18/11/16`

...however, when I format the column as date, time or custom, the existing cells do not format.

I've also tried `=DATEVALUE(A2)` but it returns a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: Try `=INT(A2)` It will return just the date part of the value.

Comment: **do format** or **do not format** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ask excel to parse a no-standard format date. Furthermore, `DATEVALUE` will drop the time from the value.

What you can do is separate the date and time, parse them separately and add them up:

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND(" ", A1, FIND(" ", A1)+1))) + 
 TIMEVALUE(MID(A1, 1, FIND(" ", A1)-1))
```

*If the date and time have fixed length, you can replace the `FIND` with their respective length of 8 and 5.*

Comment: I originally dismissed this until I realised I had to change instances of A1 to A2 due to my header row. Your formula automates a lot of things I would have having to do manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**To get the time from this cell:**

```
=LEFT(A2,5)
```

**To get the date from this cell:**

```
=RIGHT(A2,8)
```

**To get the weekday text from this cell:**

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A2;LEN(A2)-9);LEN(LEFT(A2;LEN(A2)-9))-6)
```

Alternatively, you can use the date portion to find the weekday directly:

```
=TEXT(RIGHT(A2,8), "ddd")
OR
=TEXT(RIGHT(A2,8), "dddd")
```

And to get the weekday in numbers:

```
=WEEKDAY(RIGHT(A2,8))
```

Comment: I extracted the date into a new column (K) and the time into a new column (L). I then combined both into a new column (M) and formatted the cells as required.